# Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.Core not working

Tags: c#, .net

I try to run this command `Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.Core` in Nuget console but it does nothing :/

[image]

Comment: Did you try to press `Enter` button after that? What version o VS do you use? Try to update Nuget

Answer (score 0):

You could try these:

1. Try to do the same using the GUI. Right click in the project -> Manage Nuget Packages.
2. Check your nuget sources (although looks good in the screenshot)
3. Check the references in you project. Sometimes the file packages.config contains an entry with the same package and the command does nothing because the target package is already there. If that's the case, delete the reference, delete the entry for the package on the package.config file and try the command again.

Hope this helps.